# Add 1 month to the date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to Add 1 month to the date value(1st row) and use it as the input to the next row to add the month till it reaches the maximum month id.

```
declare @tmp table (date date,month_id int);
insert into @tmp values('2014-11-30',1),('2014-11-30',2),('2014-11-30',3),('2014-11-30',4),('2014-11-30',5),('2014-11-30',6),('2015-01-01',1),('2015-01-01',2),('2015-01-01',3),('2015-01-01',4);
```

[image: Result Set]

Expected output:

```
DATE        month_id    derived_date1 
2014-11-30      1       2014-12-30 
2014-11-30      2       2015-01-30 
2014-11-30      3       2015-02-28 
2014-11-30      4       2015-03-28 
2014-11-30      5       2015-04-28 
2014-11-30      6       2015-05-28 
2015-01-01      1       2015-02-01 
2015-01-01      2       2015-03-01 
2015-01-01      3       2015-04-01 
2015-01-01      4       2015-05-01
```

Comment: Please show desired resultset. Your description is  not clear. Plus I guess that you are using `SQL Server`.

Comment: In standard SQL you can do `date_column + interval '1' month`. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: expected output:
DATE month_id derived_date1
2014-11-30 1 2014-12-30
2014-11-30 2 2015-01-30
2014-11-30 3 2015-02-28
2014-11-30 4 2015-03-28
2014-11-30 5 2015-04-28
2014-11-30 6 2015-05-28
2015-01-01 1 2015-02-01
2015-01-01 2 2015-03-01
2015-01-01 3 2015-04-01
2015-01-01 4 2015-05-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE

```
declare @tmp table (date date,month_id int);
insert into @tmp values('2014-11-30',1),('2014-11-30',2),('2014-11-30',3),('2014-11-30',4),('2014-11-30',5),('2014-11-30',6),('2015-01-01',1),('2015-01-01',2),('2015-01-01',3),('2015-01-01',4);

;with cte as
(
    select date, month_id, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date) as derived_date1 from @tmp where month_id = 1
    union all select t.date, t.month_id, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte.derived_date1) from cte inner join @tmp t on cte.date = t.date and cte.month_id = t.month_id - 1
)
select * from cte order by date, month_id
```

Comment: thank you Eric it works...i tried this  and missed the '-1'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

The `DATEADD()` function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

```
    Declare @tmp table (date date,month_id int);
    Insert into @tmp values('2014-11-30',1),('2014-11-30',2),('2014-11-30',3),('2014-11-30',4),('2014-11-30',5),('2014-11-30',6),('2015-01-01',1),('2015-01-01',2),('2015-01-01',3),('2015-01-01',4);
    SELECT date as Original_Date,month_id as Month_Id,DATEADD(MONTH,month_id,date) as Derived_date from @tmp
```

[image: Result Set]

Comment: i want the 1st row output as the  input to the 2nd row and so on...the above query i tried earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a number or tally table

```
declare @numbers table(no int)
insert into @numbers 
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6 union all
select 7 union all
select 8 union all
select 9 union all
select 10 union all
select 11 union all
select 12 

declare @month_value int, @date datetime
select @month_value=12, @date='2014-01-30'

declare @tmp table (date date,month_id int);
insert into @tmp 
select dateadd(month,no-1,@date),no from @numbers where no<=@month_value

select * from @tmp
```

Comment: expected output:
DATE month_id derived_date1 
2014-11-30 1 2014-12-30 
2014-11-30 2 2015-01-30 
2014-11-30 3 2015-02-28 
2014-11-30 4 2015-03-28 
2014-11-30 5 2015-04-28 
2014-11-30 6 2015-05-28 
2015-01-01 1 2015-02-01 
2015-01-01 2 2015-03-01 
2015-01-01 3 2015-04-01 
2015-01-01 4 2015-05-01

Answer (score 0):

For a given date and a month range you could use a CTE and a join on the data:

```
declare @StartMonth int = 1
declare @EndMonth int = 6

declare @DateToPopulate Date = '2014-11-30'
declare @tmp table (original date,month_id int, derived date)
;

with month_range as
(
    select @StartMonth as Month
    union all
    select Month+1 from month_range where Month+1 <=@EndMonth
),
generated_data as
(
    select @DateToPopulate as OriginalDate, Month as MonthID, DATEADD(month,Month,@DateToPopulate) as DerivedDate
    from month_range
)
insert into @tmp
select * from generated_data
```